# ASP.NET C# FileUpload inside UpdatePanel with Postback

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, exception

currently i'm trying to upload an image via a FileUpload and store it in a database. My problem is that when i click the upload-button, i always get a System.NullReferenceException when trying to upload.

Now i know that there are issues with asp-FileUploads inside an UpdatePanel - so i set the upload-button as an PostBackTrigger which causes a full postback - but it's still not working.

Thats what i got so far:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update_woundpic" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="woundpic_upload" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3 class="label2">Upload
                    <small class="text-muted">maximal 5MB</small>
                  </h3>
                  <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadWoundImage" runat="server" />
                  <br />
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="woundpic_upload" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Upload_Click" CssClass="btn3d btn btn-default btn-lg"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Hochladen</asp:LinkButton>
                  <asp:Label ID="lbl_success" runat="server" Text="Upload erfolgreich!" CssClass="uploadSuccess" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Label ID="lbl_error" runat="server" Text="Upload nicht erfolgreich!" CssClass="uploadFailure" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                  <br />
                  <br />
            </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And this is my method to upload the image / file:

```
 protected void btn_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            byte[] imgByte;

                using(BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(uploadWoundImage.PostedFile.InputStream))
                {
                    imgByte = reader.ReadBytes(uploadWoundImage.PostedFile.ContentLength);
                }

            DateTime imageUpload = DateTime.Now;
            string imageFormat = uploadWoundImage.PostedFile.ContentType;
            string imageName = Path.GetFileName(uploadWoundImage.PostedFile.FileName);
            _db.SaveWoundImage(imgByte, imageFormat, imageName, imageUpload);

        }
```

Now, if i click the button the line

```
using(BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(uploadWoundImage.PostedFile.InputStream))
```

throws the System.NullReferenceException, so i don't know why the file isn't found even with a full postback.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `FileUpload` doesn't produce events. You should set `PostBackTrigger` to the `Button`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply - but its set to the button, just compare the ID of the LinkButton (woundpic_upload) to the postback-Trigger which is set in the updatePanel!

Comment: Make sure that the HTML `form` has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`